# incompatible types error in java with strings and text

Tags: java, string, text, bluej

I am trying to make a setter method for a label but i keep on getting the same error, after trying multiple solutions I came up with, I still can't figure out why what I'm doing is wrong. I keep on getting this error: "incompatible types: java.lang.string cannot be converted to text". This is my full code:

```
    public class Bar {
    // the numeric value of the bar
    private int value;
    // the rectangle representing the bar
    private Rectangle view;
    // The text label for this bar
    private Text label;
    // The value as a text object
    private Text valueText;

    /**
     * Constructor for a bar object.  The rectangle for the bar is
     * also constructed here and its size is set to the given height.
     * The value of the bar is initialised to 0.
     * If there is a label for the bar, a Text object is created using the 
     * text of the label and the colour of the label set to black.
     * The bar and the label are not visible until the display method
     * is called.
     *
     * @param label The label for the bar.
     * @param width The height of the bar.
     */
    public Bar(java.lang.String label, int height) {
        value = 0;
        view = new Rectangle();
        view.changeSize(0, height);
        this.label = new Text(label);

    }
    public void display() {
        view.makeVisible();
        label.makeVisible();
    }

    public int setValue(int val) {
        this.value = val;
        return val;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;

    }

    public Rectangle getView() {
        return view;
    }

    public void setLabel(java.lang.String text) {
        label  = text;
    }

    public Text getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public void setColor(java.lang.String color) {
        view.changeColor(color);
    }

    public java.lang.String getColors() {
        return view.getColorName();
    }

    public void setPosition(int x, int y) {
        label.setPosition(x,y);

    }

}
```

This is the source code of the text class:

```
import acm.graphics.GLabel;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;

/**
* Write a description of class Text here.
*
* @author (your name)
* @version (a version number or a date)
*/
public class Text extends Drawable
{
private String fontName = "arial";
private String fontStyle = "plain";
private int fontSize = 18;

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Text
 */
public Text(String text)
{
    // initialise instance variables
    object = new GLabel(text);
    this.setFill(false);
    changeColor("black");
    ((GLabel)object).setFont(createFont());
    add(((GLabel)object));
    setLocation(100, 200);
    markAsComplete();
}

private String createFont() {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    sb.append(fontName);
    sb.append("-");
    sb.append(fontStyle);
    sb.append("-");
    sb.append(fontSize);
    return sb.toString();
}

public void setText(String newText) {
    ((GLabel)object).setLabel(newText);
}

/**
 * Change the font size of the text to a given value. The value of newSize
 * must be >= 0.
 * 
 * @param newSize
 *            the new font size of the text.
 */
public void changeSize(int newSize) {
    this.fontSize = newSize;
    ((GLabel)object).setFont(createFont());
}

/**
 * Print the names of all the available fonts.
 */
public void printFonts() {
    GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment
        .getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    String[] names = ge.getAvailableFontFamilyNames();
    for (String name : names) {
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}

/**
 * The name of the current font.
 */
public String getFontName() {
    return ((GLabel)object).getFont().getFontName();
}

/**
 * Find the width of the text in the selected font.
 * 
 * @return the width of the text
 */
public int getTextWidth() {
    return (int) ((GLabel)object).getWidth();
}

/**
 * Find the height of the text in the selected font.
 * 
 * @return the height of the text
 */
public int getTextHeight() {
    return (int) ((GLabel)object).getHeight(); 
}

public String getText() {
    return ((GLabel)object).getLabel();
}
```

}

Comment: Can you share the definition of the Text class?

Answer (score 0):

In your `setLabel()` setter, you are trying to assign a reference of an object of type `String` to a field `label` of type `Text` and the compiler tells you this is not possible.

You can fix it the same way as you do in the constructor:

```
public void setLabel(java.lang.String text) {
  label  = new Text(text);
}
```

Note that a setter should take a `Text` object as parameter, so you may think about changing it to `setLabel(Text text)` and then using it with string in that way: `yourObject.setLabel(new Text("yourStringLabel"))`.

Comment: I already tried both ways, when I use new Text(text), what happens is that the new text appears on top of the old text but doesnt replace it, and if I use setLabel(Text text) i get the same error as before.

Comment: In that case, can you post source of the `Text` class?